# Magento Categories in menu still showing disabled categories

Tags: magento

I have got this website located here using Magento 1.9.0.1

http://furnituretree.co.nz/index.php/

If you go to Lounge and Living in the menu it the first column it has two categories saying Bookcases - Over 900 and Bookcases - up to 900.

Both these categories have been disabled in Catalog > Manage Categories (Is Active is set to NO and Include in Navigation Menu has been set to NO)

However both are still showing in the menu.

These have been linked using widgets which I clicked Insert Widget > Widget Type is Catalog Category Link. Anchor Custom Text and Custom Title are blank and Ive selected the Category from the Catalog > Manage Categories area.

Am I doing something wrong? Pretty much I want it so if I disable a Category in Catalog > Manage Categories it turns it off in the menu aswell.

Thanks

Comment: anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked which store views it's set up for? You might have changed the data for the wrong one.

Comment: I disabled the French and German Store names if thats what you mean?